# How can I customize the event of sphinx.application.Sphinx.connect?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am a beginner in Sphinx and I want to understand the operation mechanism.
The following content is from this [link](https://gist.github.com/mgedmin/6052926).

```
from sphinx.application import Sphinx

def html_page_context(app, pagename, templatename, context, doctree):
    ...

def setup(app: Sphinx):
    # event:
    # from sphinx.events import core_events
    # https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#event-html-page-context
    # https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.0/ext/appapi.html#event-html-page-context
    app.connect(event='html-page-context', callback=html_page_context)
```

My question is how does he know how to write this function(`def html_page_context() ...`)?

I study in the documentation([ref1](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#event-html-page-context) and [ref2](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.0/ext/appapi.html#event-html-page-context)), and it explained that the parameters of its function should be, but how can I know how to write the **detail** in this function?

Of course, I can refer it and debugging to know what is going on. (but what if no other reference, just the native code exists.)

*Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; teach him how to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime.* Please teach me how to fish.

I hope the answerer which can tell me:

Is the event which exists a default function?

Yes:

1. Where is the location of scripts come from?
2. How do you know it?  (Is there are any skills, for example, the hook to find out, or are you the developer one of them?)

No:

- Is there are any suggestions to know how to write the content. (not to reference in from other writers, just native source code)

I know that there are some issues with some subjectivity, but I would gladly accept any 'pearls of wisdom' they are willing to impart, thinks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it, the answer is

Yes

- It's from `sphinx.builders.html.__init__.py setup()`
- Use the search to searching the `sphinx` project.

---

a simple way is to use the search of IDE provide.

open the path `X://.../PythonXX/Lib/site-packages/sphinx` as the project,

and then to start searching any keyword you like, for example, `html-page-context`

finally, you will find `app.connect('html-page-context', setup_js_tag_helper)`, which location in the `sphinx.builders.html.__init__.py setup()`), so the function of `setup_js_tag_helper` is the default behavior, and you can set the breakpoints to discover more interesting things.

---

## quick search

You can directly search with PyCharm.

Find in Path → Scope → All Places[image]